# What's the meaning of "きわきわ"?

Tags: meaning

What's the meaning of "**きわきわ**" ?

> A:  使えるコト話せるかな
>
> B: 大丈夫かな？
>
> C: きわきわですね｡

Answer (score 7):

It's a relatively rarely seen mimetic word that acts as adverb and noun, and means "(on) the very verge or brink" (of failure, indecency, or other dangerous thing).

Etymologically this word derives from [際【きわ】](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/58676/meaning/m0u/) ("border, limit, instant") so that has very similar meaning to [際どい](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/58695/meaning/m0u/), except that it tells vivid sensuous feeling. Synonyms are [ぎりぎり](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/58228/meaning/m0u/%E3%81%8E%E3%82%8A%E3%81%8E%E3%82%8A/), [すれすれ](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/120587/meaning/m0u/), [いっぱいいっぱい](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/13623/meaning/m0u/) etc.